# Shortcut keys that are independent to keyboard layout

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xkb

Is there a way to define an association of a particular *physical* key of the keyboard to some action, independently of the letter that this key is associated to in any layout?

**Example**: In most default Gnome shortcut key associations, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> opens a terminal. But only in the Latin keyboard layout. Doing the same *physical* action while in Greek layout does not work, since the associated letter is then the **"Greek <kbd>T</kbd>"**, not the **"Latin <kbd>T</kbd>"**.

Therefore, one has first to switch to the Latin layout and then press the shortcut key, which may be frustrating since one is never sure if the key has not been pressed correctly at the first place, so probably tries several times until realizing that the problem was in the layout.

A solution could be defining the same association for the same key in all layouts one uses - but then one would have to do this for all shortcuts, so this solution does not scale well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I often switch between English and Greek layouts and this has been a minor annoyance for a while. Your question pushed me to solve it, so thanks!

I found a program that can do this: [`xbindkeys`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xbindkeys). The proceedure I followed (adapted from [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys)) was:

1. Install `xbindkeys`. On my Debian this is done with

   ```
    sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
   ```

You should also be able to install easily enough with the equivalent `yum install` or `pacman -S` or whatever commands.

2. Create the default settings file:

   ```
    xbindkeys --defaults > ~/.xbindkeysrc
   ```
3. Get the right keycodes for your keys. Run `xbindkeys -k` and press your desired shortcut. With my keyboard at least (though this should be standard), `xbindkeys -k` reports that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> is

   ```
    m:0x14 + c:28
    Control+Mod2 + t
   ```
4. Create the relevant shortcut, add these lines to `~/.xbindkeysrc`:

   ```
    "xterm"
     m:0x14 + c:28
   ```
5. Run `xbindkeys`. The shortcut now works even in the Greek layout. To make this permanent, add this to your `~/.Xsession`:

   ```
    xbindkeys
   ```

Comment: xbindkeys does what I need. And, yes, Alt + Ctr + T is the default, not Ctrl + T. I corrected the question. I am wondering though why Gnome has chosen correspondence with letters rather than with key codes

Comment: @serxio perhaps keycodes change on different keyboards? Or you can remap things so Gnome calls the key by name so it won't be confused if you've mapped Ctrl to Alt or something? Trexa gyreye.