# Make Compose not compose after certain key presses

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, xkb, xmodmap, compose-key

On my laptop, I use the <kbd>Win</kbd> as a modifier. With the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key pressed, the key sends a different keysym and I use that as a Compose key.

```
keycode 133 = Hyper_L
keycode 134 = Multi_key
add mod4 = Hyper_L
```

I have some window manager key bindings of the form <kbd>Hyper</kbd>+<kbd>KP_*N*</kbd>. On a laptop, this requires pressing and holding <kbd>Win</kbd>, then pressing and holding <kbd>Fn</kbd>, then pressing <kbd>KP_*N*</kbd> and finally releasing everything. If I press <kbd>Fn</kbd> before <kbd>Hyper</kbd>, this sends the `Multi_key` keysym instead of `Hyper_L`, so I'm pressing Compose. I find the finger coordination required to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> before <kbd>Hyper</kbd> to be a lot less, so I'd like to be able to do that. If I then press a keypad key (which requires <kbd>Fn</kbd>), I want the key press to be interpreted as the `mod4` modifier instead of `Multi_key`.

I can add the `mod4` modifier to the `Multi_key` keysym, and this makes my window manager bindings work when I press <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>Hyper</kbd> in either order. However, if I press <kbd>Fn</kbd> first (which is how it happens naturally), this records a `Multi_key` keysym, so a key sequence like <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Hyper</kbd>+<kbd>KP_1</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>'</kbd> ends up switching to workspace 1 and inserting `á` instead of `'a`, because the application that is focused after the keyboard shortcut activates receives a key release event for `Multi_key`.

How can I have my cake and eat it?

- If I press <kbd>Hyper</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd> in either order, then press a keypad key, this should only trigger my window manager binding and not leave a pending `Compose`. Either the application should not receive a key release event for `Multi_key`, or it should receive another event (injected by the window manager) that will effectively cancel the first one.
- If I press and hold <kbd>Fn</kbd> and press <kbd>Hyper</kbd>, then release them both, this should send a press and release event for `Multi_key`.

I don't mind whether this is done through a change of my keyboard configuration, or of my window manager bindings, or both. The window manager is sawfish, so it's pretty flexible.

If the solution involves XKB, I don't want to define my whole keyboard configuration through XKB. The XKB part should focus on defining a group for the affected keys (or whatever it takes).

Comment: Have a look at my answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91433/22222). You might be able to use `xbindkeys` for this.

Comment: @terdon I don't see how this helps. Executing something after a key press isn't my problem — my window manager can do this just as well.

Comment: I was thinking that if you set up your shortcuts through `xbindkeys` you _might_ be able to get consistent behavior irrespective of the order in which they were pressed. No idea if this would work but it might be worth a shot.