# Is it possible to make keybindings for mpv to run shell scripts?

Tags: shell-script, keyboard-shortcuts, mpv

I'd like to change my webcam's **exposure-time** & **gain**... using something like `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c gain=15`.

As far I searched, the keybindings for mpv is located/configured at `~/.config/mpv/input.conf`.
However, I couldn't find anywhere on internet "How to execute external shell scripts from mpv's keybindings". Is this possible?

Comment: Why is mpv relevant? Didn't you say all you want is to assign a command to a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: I intend this to use on different distros with different DEs. If I get it configure on mpv, then I don't have to configure it on each desktop environment (I suppose each one is different than the other). Instead, I just copy one mpv config file.

Comment: But how is `mpv` relevant here? You are showing us a command called `v4l2-ctl`. What does this have to do with `mpv`? Are you maybe looking for something like `xkeybinds`? Have a look at my answer here: [Shortcut keys that are independent to keyboard layout](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91433). Does that do what you need? You can still copy the `~/.xbindkeysrc` file anywhere you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [run](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#command-interface-%5B-%5D%5D%5D) command. Add for example this line to `~/.config/mpv/input.conf` if you want to copy the current playback position to your Wayland clipboard when you press <kbd>y</kbd>:

```
y run "/bin/sh" "-c" "printf %s ${=time-pos} | wl-copy"
```

See also [§ Command interface](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#command-interface) in the manual.

However, I agree with terdon that you don't need mpv in this case.